# Recyclerview unswipe item

Tags: android, swipe, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with a Recyclerview. I managed to implement swipe to dismiss; the swiped item is deleted and Snackbar prompts the user to undelete.

What I would like to achieve is after an item is completely swiped, I want to show a dialog to confirm deletion. If user refuses, I want to reshow the swiped item (preferably by sliding it in the opposite direction of the original swipe). But how can I *unswipe* an item.

Can anybody help me? Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save your dismissed item and position in variables 
if user presses cancel/undo just add them back into your recylcerView adapter

Comment: Shame we didn't get an answer to the original question.  When deletion results in a one way operation (eg deleting a record), this cannot always be undone